# How to measure box / parcel dimensions without using AI kit on android phone

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality, measurement, dimensional-modeling

I am looking for a solution which I can implement in my app. Basically I do offer online courier service domestic and international and enter has to enter volumetric weight for their parcel /box but in 99% of the cases, weights are incorrect.

How do I resolve this issue so that even a simple user who doesn't have high-end AR Kit enabled Andorid device can also measure dimension of box. I can take Debit Card as a reference object.

Comment: Your question is quite broad, and answering it would require describing how to do many things and/or designing a sizable program. While there's likely a way to do all of that, you're more likely to get an answer if you start implementing it yourself. When you get stuck, include what you've done so far (with code!), and which specific part you're stuck on. Describe the exact behavior you want for that part, as well as how that differs from what you have so far. Include the text of any errors. The more detail you give, the more answers you're likely to get. See the [FAQ] and [ask] for more info.

Comment: (In this case, it's a very difficult problem, especially to support all devices, which is part of why AR Kit only supports some devices)

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of this in the OpenCV source here: [squares.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp)

Obviously this isn't coded in an android compatible code; however, there are many examples for android in the samples directory.

1. Instruct user to take two pictures. First with card flat next to parcel, Second with card vertical pressed to parcels sid.
2. Accept pictures from user.
3. Use methods in square.cpp to detect all rectangles in both images.
4. Display results to user and allow them to adjust rectangles for accuracy.
5. Take the small rectangle (debit/credit card), and use rectangle dimensions and image pixel dimensions to determine pixels per inch or mm.
6. Take the larger rectangle (parcel), and use pixels per inch or mm from step 5 + rectangle dimensions to determine length and width from picture one, and depth/height from picture two.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing as I am highly obliged by your help.

Comment: @PrateekSharma, please don't forget to mark as answer if this answered your question.